# How to move a record from rs1 to rs2 (ADODB.Recordsets) with VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access, adodb

In Access, I have `rs1` and `rs2`, both `As ADODB.Recordset`, they have the same fields. I want to move a record/row from `rs1` to `rs2`.

I know how to do it with `SQL` or `rs2.AddNew` and iterating over the `Fields`, but I'd like to do it by using the `ADODB.Record` - Object, something like this.

```
Dim rs1 As ADODB.Recordset
Dim rs2 As ADODB.Recordset
...

Private Sub MoveRecord (id As Long)

  Dim r As ADODB.Record

  rs1.filter = "id=" & id

  Set r = rs1(0)

  ' And now??? rs2.Addnew r is rubbish...


End Sub
```

I tried the `Record.MoveRecord`-method but it seems this is for moving files?

```
Record.MoveRecord (Source, Destination, UserName, Password, Options, Async)
```

`Source` and `Destination` are `Strings`, not `RecordSet`s.

**Can this be done, and if so, how?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you feel such a function is necessary, you can write it yourself...

```
Public Sub MoveCurrentRecord(rsSource, rsTarget)
   rsTarget.AddNew
   Dim fld
   For Each fld In rsSource.Fields
      rsTarget.Fields(fld.Name).Value = fld.Value
   Next
   rsTarget.Update
End If
```

Works with both ADO and DAO, and with both a record and a recordset as the source object. Note that you might want to implement additional logic to skip autonumber fields.

Comment: So it's impossible to do it with a `record` object?

Comment: There's no built-in for it. But as I said, this function works fine if `rsSource` is actually a record and not a recordset. Also, there are very, very little use cases for an `ADODB.Record`